# access an array element inside a LINQ to Entities set

Tags: c#, linq

I am using a Split method on a string inside a Linq query but only need the second element.  I get a "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex'"  on the below code:

```
    var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                         join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                         where line.RmaNumber != null 
                         &&
                         (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) &&
                         line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                         && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                         select new
                         {
                             dtCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
                             UniqueIdNo = rma.UniqueIdNo,
                             RmaNumber = line.RmaNumber,
                             RmaOriginalUniqueId = line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                             ItemSequenceNo = line.ItemSequenceNo,
                             ItemNumber = line.ItemNumber,
                             goodRMA_flag =  line.RmaNumber.Contains("/078"),
                             rmaGood = line.RmaNumber.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
                         }).ToArray();
```

if I remove the [1] on the  array it works and I can access both elements fine for the entire dataset with:

```
  foreach (var item in RMA_stops_all)
        {
         var right = RMA_stops_all.First().rmaGood[1];
         var left = RMA_stops_all.First().rmaGood[0];
            Console.WriteLine("left {0} - right{1} ",left.ToString(), right.ToString());
        }
```

EDIT - duh.  The above "test" was completely useless (as gently pointed out) - however, the below does prove out that it is working correctly (some of the returned values only have 1 element, hence the additional if block - the output is as expected:

```
 foreach (var item in RMA_stops_all)
            {
                string right, left;
                if (item.rmaGood.Length == 1)
                {
                     left = item.rmaGood[0].ToString();
                     right = "Not there";
                }
                else
                {
                 left = item.rmaGood[0].ToString();
                 right = item.rmaGood[1].ToString();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("left {0} - right{1} ", left, right);
            }
```

SQL Output from dbMonitor:

```
SELECT t2.datetime_created AS "DatetimeCreated", 
       t1.unique_id_no AS "UniqueIdNo", 
       t2.rma_number AS "RmaNumber", 
       t2.rma_original_unique_id AS "RmaOriginalUniqueId",
       t2.item_sequence_no AS "ItemSequenceNo", 
       t2.item_number AS "ItemNumber", 
       (t2.rma_number LIKE :p3) OR (t2.rma_number LIKE :p4) AS "C1",
       t2.rma_number AS "RmaNumber1"
FROM cops_reporting.distribution_stop_information t1
INNER JOIN cops_reporting.distribution_line_items t2 
    ON t1.unique_id_no = t2.unique_id_no
WHERE (t2.rma_number IS NOT NULL) 
   AND (t2.datetime_created > :p0)
   AND (t2.datetime_created < :p1)
   AND (t1.customer_no = :p2)
```

Comment: EF supports `String.Split`? How SQL query looks like?

Comment: Seems like there is no string splitting

Comment: and yet it runs and returns an array that I can access?

Comment: I don't see it in the SQL either, is LINQ doing it post results coming back?

Comment: I am using the postgresql data connector from DevArt -- would that make a difference?

Comment: Your example of it working with the whole array is bad because you `foreach` with `item` but don't reference item in your body.

Comment: absolutely correct NetMage -- I saw what I wanted to see!  Corrected in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize Linq to Entities had access to some SQL functions directly, so this may work for you:

```
var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                     join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                     where line.RmaNumber != null 
                     &&
                     (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) &&
                     line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                     && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                     select new
                     {
                         dtCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
                         UniqueIdNo = rma.UniqueIdNo,
                         RmaNumber = line.RmaNumber,
                         RmaOriginalUniqueId = line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                         ItemSequenceNo = line.ItemSequenceNo,
                         ItemNumber = line.ItemNumber,
                         goodRMA_flag =  line.RmaNumber.Contains("/078"),
                         rmaGood = line.RmaNumber.Substring(line.RmaNumber.IndexOf("/")+1)
                     }).ToArray();
```

assuming that RmaNumber looks like #/# and doesn't have additional slashes you want to avoid.

Comment: Substring vs Substr - SO won't accept a 3 character edit so I could not just change that. Otherwise - yes, the above does indeed work. It however does not address the original question of how (or that it is not possible) to access the elements generated by a split function. Nice solution however to the actual problem and clever use of IndexOf -- I had forgotten about that!

Comment: Thanks - fixed the typo. Too many languages in my head! Testing with MS SQL, it seems like regardless of documentation at some point MS implemented String.Split() in Linq to SQL/EF, apparently handled on the client side, but not array indexing or other processing with arrays (e.g. Last()).

Comment: Also, apparently only in a final select (e.g. trying to selectmany a split causes a not implemented in SQL error).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would work without the index operation either, and your SQL doesn't seem to reflect the same Linq code (have you used LinqPad?), but I would suggest since you are doing .ToArray() anyway, moving the split/index to the client:

```
var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                     join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                     where line.RmaNumber != null 
                     &&
                     (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) &&
                     line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                     && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                     select new
                     {
                         dtCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
                         rma.UniqueIdNo,
                         line.RmaNumber,
                         line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                         line.ItemSequenceNo,
                         line.ItemNumber,
                         goodRMA_flag =  line.RmaNumber.Contains("/078"),
                     }).AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
                         r.dtCreated,
                         r.UniqueIdNo,
                         r.RmaNumber,
                         r.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                         r.ItemSequenceNo,
                         r.ItemNumber,
                         r.goodRMA_flag,
                         rmaGood = r.RmaNumber.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
                     });
```

BTW, you don't have to repeat field/property names for a simple accessor expression so I removed them from your original select. Also, if you can live with the double indirection, you could just include r in the second select.